# Record audio and video from webcam using Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, desktop-application

I'm new to JavaFx. I would like to record a video along with audio in a desktop application. I'm able to connect to the webcam of my machine, but having no clue to achieve this functionality. Can anyone share across on how to achieve this? It would be really helpful.

Comment: as far as I'm aware you can't do this without involving 3rd party solution. Quick google shows https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-javafx as viable solution?

Comment: @Adam - I have tried this, but its coming as searching for devices. I developing on a MAC.

Answer (score 0):

For capturing only images from desktop webcams there is a nice and simple to use api `Webcam Capture`. Find it [here](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/). Github link is [here](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-javafx)

However there is one that also helps with audio and video capturing but is not open source. Its called `JxCapture`. Find it [here](https://www.teamdev.com/jxcapture#licensing-pricing).